# How to create a post with image on LinkedIn with LinkedIn Developer API?

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

So I was trying to use the LinkedIn Developer API to post some text with a image or multiple images at once.

So here's the issue

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin

This is the DOCS for the share on LinkedIn that is completely working fine when am posting just text.

But the issue arises when I try to create Post with Image

1. https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload This API is giving me an error like this.

```
{
    "serviceErrorCode": 65600,
    "message": "Invalid access token",
    "status": 401
}
```

Even I refreshed the token to check if there was an issue with my token. My access token is working fine with sharing the text-only post.

2. If your above API works fine in case then you are registered for uploading file. Then you'll receive the below URL from the response. But they mentioned it with CURL and I want to send a cross-origin request from Axios. I tried a curl converter but that doesn't explain how we will upload the file with the request.

`curl -i --upload-file /Users/peter/Desktop/superneatimage.png --header "Authorization: Bearer redacted" 'https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5522AQGTYER3k3ByHQ/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQJbrN86Zm265gAAAWemyz2pxPSgONtBiZdchrgG872QltnfYjnMdb2j3A&app=1953784&sync=0&v=beta&ut=2H-IhpbfXrRow1'`

3. I have the file either in URL or in Base64 format. I don't have a binary file present in my case. Well, I want to send a binary file too for a default case but for most requests, I'll be using the URL for the image.

Thanks for reading the whole question. Please help me with the information you have that can be useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
            public function linkedInPost()
            {
                $accessToken = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN";
                $company_id = "urn:li:organization:YOUR_COMPANY_ID";
                $post_title="hello this is text post";
                //for only one image
                $imagePath=public_path('media/misc/bg-2.jpg');
                $register_image_request=[
                    "registerUploadRequest"=> [
                        "recipes"=> [
                            "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-image"
                        ],
                        "owner"=> "$company_id",
                        "serviceRelationships"=> [
                            [
                                "relationshipType"=> "OWNER",
                                "identifier"=>"urn:li:userGeneratedContent"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ];
                $register_post = Http::post("https://api.linkedin.com/v2/assets?action=registerUpload&oauth2_access_token=$accessToken", $register_image_request);
                $register_post=json_decode($register_post,true);
                $upload_url=$register_post['value']['uploadMechanism']['com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MediaUploadHttpRequest']['uploadUrl'];
                $upload_assets=$register_post['value']['asset'];

                $response = Http::withHeaders(['Authorization' => "Bearer $accessToken"])->withBody(file_get_contents($imagePath), '')->put($upload_url);
                
                $request = [
                    "author" => "$company_id",
                    "lifecycleState" => "PUBLISHED",
                    "specificContent" => [
                        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent" => [
                            "shareCommentary" => [
                                "text" => $post_title
                            ],
                            "shareMediaCategory"=> "IMAGE",
                            "media"=> [
                                [
                                    "status"=> "READY",
                                    "media"=> $upload_assets,
                                ]
                            ]
                        ],
                    ],
                    "visibility" => [
                        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility" => "PUBLIC",
                    ]
                ];
                $post_url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/ugcPosts?oauth2_access_token=" . $accessToken;
                $post = Http::post($post_url, $request);
                return $post;
            }
```

This is working code in laravel

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).